# Alternate name for "Guess and Check"?

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

If I solve part of a problem using "Guess and Check," what should I call it in the solution? Something that sounds like actual thinking was involved.

Comment: ["By inspection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon#Proof_techniques).  E.g. one can see that the quadratic $x^2+5x+6$ factors as $(x+2)(x+3)$ by inspection.

Comment: @JMoravitz That's what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Note that the "guess" might not be a unique solution. See for example $x^2=1$ and you "guess" $x=1$

Comment: Trial and error, perhaps?

Comment: Don't be ashamed to admit that we guess.  Relevant video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KmimDq4cSU (Specifically, I'm referring to Feynman's comment at 7 seconds into the video.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that "guess and check," "inspection," and "trial and error" are all acceptable things to put. Everyone does it, and everyone knows that everyone does it. I don't see why you would have anything to gain from hiding it, and don't think of it as something to be ashamed of. Often you just know things - that's a sign of being familiar with the material. Of course, once you've found the correct answer you still need to justify it. But often being able to pick factors or limits out of thin air (or wolfram alpha) and proving that they are right is much easier than deriving them.

I would recommend **not** saying that you made an ansatz because I'm a professional mathematician and native English speaker and I had to look that word up. Whoever is reading your result will far more likely be annoyed with than impressed by your use of that word.

Comment: +1 for explaining that it's ok to guess and I would add even more upvotes for the last paragraph.

Comment: For what it's worth "ansatz" shows up here on Math.SE hundreds of times http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=ansatz

Answer (score 1):

You made an [ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz). Sounds very fancy.

Comment: Unless you come from German speaking country when it will not sound as fancy. And if you are not, chances are that many will have no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: @Ennar Hey, some people like learning new words... The other suggestions aren't at all bad, but this thread wouldn't be complete without a mention of this. It does show up on occasion whether you want it to or not.

Comment: In mathematical usage, an ansatz is slightly more than a guess; it's a guess that a pattern applies. If I want to solve the recurrence $x_n = 2x_{n-1}+1$, with $x_0=0$, guessing would be deciding to try $x_n = 2^n-1$ and seeing that it works; an ansatz would be assuming that  $x_n$ has the form $A\cdot 2^n + B$, and solving for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: OP asked the question for practical purposes. I've read mathematical literature in English and never encountered this term in practical use. Since you don't discuss it in your answer, I made a comment so OP is aware.

Comment: This term was commonplace in my undergrad physics and math classes in the US.